# Turbo C++ (BGI library (graphics.h)) Connect 4 AI implementation problem

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

There is this issue i am facing with my connect 4 project. The AI algorithms seem to be just placing pieces in a single column and are not following their algorithms properly. I am compiling this in Turbo C++ using the BGI library.

Here is the code:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <iostream.h>

const int rows = 6;
const int cols = 7;
const int winCondition = 4;
const int cellSize = 67;

int board[rows][cols] = {0};
int currentPlayer = 1;
int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}

void drawBoard();
int getPlayerMove();
int checkWin(int player);
void drawMenu();
void drawAIMenu();
void clearBoard();
int getMenuChoice();
int getAIMenuChoice();
int easyAIMove();
int mediumAIMove();
int difficultAIMove();
int minimax(int depth, int isMaximizingPlayer, int alpha, int beta);

void drawBoard() {
    int x, y;
    setcolor(BLUE);
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, LIGHTGRAY);
    rectangle(87, 50, 87 + cols * cellSize, 50 + rows * cellSize);
    floodfill(51, 51, 0);

    setcolor(CYAN);
    settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(25, 155, "C");
    outtextxy(25, 175, "O");
    outtextxy(25, 195, "N");
    outtextxy(25, 215, "N");
    outtextxy(25, 235, "E");
    outtextxy(25, 255, "C");
    outtextxy(25, 275, "T");
    outtextxy(25, 305, "4");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    y = 50 + i * cellSize;
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        x = 87 + j * cellSize;
        setcolor(BLUE);
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, BLUE);
        circle(x + cellSize / 2, y + cellSize / 2, cellSize / 2);
        floodfill(x + cellSize / 2, y + cellSize / 2, 0);
        if (board[i][j] == 1) {
        setcolor(RED);
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, RED);
        circle(x + cellSize / 2, y + cellSize / 2, cellSize / 2 - 5);
        floodfill(x + cellSize / 2, y + cellSize / 2, RED);
        } else if (board[i][j] == 2) {
        setcolor(YELLOW);
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, YELLOW);
        circle(x + cellSize / 2, y + cellSize / 2, cellSize / 2 - 5);
        floodfill(x + cellSize / 2, y + cellSize / 2, YELLOW);
        }
    }
    }
}

int getPlayerMove() {
    int x = 0;
    while (1) {
    if (kbhit()) {
        int key = getch();
        if (key == 27) {
        closegraph();
        exit(0);
        } else if (key == 75 && x > 0) { // left arrow
        x--;
        } else if (key == 77 && x < cols - 1) { // right arrow
        x++;
        } else if (key == 13 && board[0][x] == 0) { // enter key
        return x;
        }
        drawBoard();
        setcolor(BLUE);
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, BLACK);
        rectangle(87, 50, 87 + cols * cellSize, 50 + rows * cellSize);
        floodfill(86, 50, 0);
        setcolor(currentPlayer == 1 ? RED : YELLOW);
        circle(86 + x * cellSize + cellSize / 2, 20, cellSize / 2 - 5);
        floodfill(86 + x * cellSize + cellSize / 2, 20, currentPlayer == 1 ? RED : YELLOW);
    }
    }
}

int easyAIMove() {
    int x;
    do {
    x = rand() % cols;
    } while (board[0][x] != 0);
    return x;
}

int mediumAIMove() {
    // First, check if AI can win in the next move
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    if (board[0][i] == 0) {
        board[0][i] = 2;
        if (checkWin(2)) {
        board[0][i] = 0;
        return i;
        }
        board[0][i] = 0;
    }
    }

    // Next, check if player can win in the next move and block it
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    if (board[0][i] == 0) {
        board[0][i] = 1;
        if (checkWin(1)) {
        board[0][i] = 0;
        return i;
        }
        board[0][i] = 0;
    }
    }

    // Otherwise, make a random move
    return easyAIMove();
}


int difficultAIMove() {
    int bestMove = -1;
    int bestScore = -10000;

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    if (board[0][i] == 0) {
        board[0][i] = 2;
        int score = minimax(4, 0, -10000, 10000);
        board[0][i] = 0;
        if (score > bestScore) {
        bestScore = score;
        bestMove = i;
        }
    }
    }

    return bestMove;
}

int minimax(int depth, int isMaximizingPlayer, int alpha, int beta) {
    int result = checkWin(1);
    if (result == 1) {
    return -1000 + depth;
    }

    result = checkWin(2);
    if (result == 1) {
    return 1000 - depth;
    }

    if (depth == 0) {
    return 0;
    }

    if (isMaximizingPlayer) {
    int maxEval = -10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        if (board[0][i] == 0) {
        board[0][i] = 2;
        int eval = minimax(depth - 1, 0, alpha, beta);
        board[0][i] = 0;
        maxEval = max(maxEval, eval);
        alpha = max(alpha, eval);
        if (beta <= alpha) {
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return maxEval;
    } else {
    int minEval = 10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        if (board[0][i] == 0) {
        board[0][i] = 1;
        int eval = minimax(depth - 1, 1, alpha, beta);
        board[0][i] = 0;
        minEval = min(minEval, eval);
        beta = min(beta, eval);
        if (beta <= alpha) {
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return minEval;
    }
}

int checkWin(int player) {
    // Check horizontally
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols - winCondition; j++) {
            int won = 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < winCondition; k++) {
                if (board[i][j + k] != player) {
                    won = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (won) return 1;
        }
    }

    // Check vertically
    for (i = 0; i <= rows - winCondition; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            int won = 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < winCondition; k++) {
                if (board[i + k][j] != player) {
                    won = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (won) return 1;
        }
    }

    // Check diagonally (top left to bottom right)
    for (i = 0; i <= rows - winCondition; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols - winCondition; j++) {
            int won = 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < winCondition; k++) {
                if (board[i + k][j + k] != player) {
                    won = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (won) return 1;
        }
    }

    // Check diagonally (bottom left to top right)
    for (i = winCondition - 1; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols - winCondition; j++) {
            int won = 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < winCondition; k++) {
                if (board[i - k][j + k] != player) {
                    won = 0;
            break;
                }
            }
            if (won) return 1;
        }
    }

    // Check for a draw (if all columns are full)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    if (board[0][j] == 0) {
        return 0; // Not a draw yet, continue the game
    }
    }

    return 0;
}

void drawMenu() {
    setcolor(LIGHTBLUE);
    settextstyle(50, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(38, 19, "________________________________________________________________________");
    settextstyle(50, VERT_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(39, 26, "______________________________________________________");
    settextstyle(50, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(38, 450, "________________________________________________________________________");
    settextstyle(50, VERT_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(614, 26, "______________________________________________________");
    setcolor(LIGHTMAGENTA);
    settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 4);
    outtextxy(135, 75, "CONNECT FOUR");
    setcolor(LIGHTBLUE);
    settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(290, 170, "MENU");
    setcolor(LIGHTCYAN);
    outtextxy(148, 227, "1. Play against Human");
    outtextxy(148, 262, "2. Play against AI");
    outtextxy(148, 297, "3. Quit");
    setcolor(LIGHTGRAY);
    outtextxy(130, 385, "Enter your choice (1-3):");
}

void drawAIMenu() {
     setcolor(LIGHTBLUE);
     settextstyle(50, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
     outtextxy(38, 19, "________________________________________________________________________");
     settextstyle(50, VERT_DIR, 2);
     outtextxy(39, 26, "______________________________________________________");
     settextstyle(50, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
     outtextxy(38, 450, "________________________________________________________________________");
     settextstyle(50, VERT_DIR, 2);
     outtextxy(614, 26, "______________________________________________________");
     setcolor(WHITE);
     settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
     outtextxy(140, 80, "AI Level");
     settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
     setcolor(GREEN);
     outtextxy(148, 193, "1. Easy");
     setcolor(YELLOW);
     outtextxy(148, 228, "2. Medium");
     setcolor(RED);
     outtextxy(148, 263, "3. Difficult");
     setcolor(WHITE);
     outtextxy(148, 298, "4. Back");
     setcolor(LIGHTGRAY);
     outtextxy(130, 380, "Enter your choice (1-4):");
}

int getMenuChoice() {
    char choice;
    while (1) {
    if (kbhit()) {
        choice = getch();
        if (choice >= '1' && choice <= '3') {
        return choice - '0';
        }
    }
    }
}

int getAIMenuChoice() {
    char aichoice;
    while (1) {
    if (kbhit()) {
        aichoice = getch();
        if (aichoice >= '1' && aichoice <= '4') {
        return aichoice - '0';
        }
    }
    }
}

void clearBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        board[i][j] = 0;
    }
    }
}

int main() {
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");

    drawMenu();
    int menuChoice;
    int aimenuChoice;

    clearBoard();

    while (menuChoice != 3) {
        cleardevice();

        if (menuChoice == 1) {
            settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
        setcolor(RED);
        outtextxy(185, 205, "Player 1: RED");
        setcolor(YELLOW);
        outtextxy(185, 235, "Player 2: YELLOW");
        delay(1700);
        cleardevice();
        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
        setcolor(LIGHTGRAY);
        outtextxy(240, 215, "Loading...");
        delay(1300);

        clearBoard();

        currentPlayer = 1;
        int gameover = 0;
          int draw = 0;
        while (!gameover) {
        cleardevice();
        drawBoard();
        int column = getPlayerMove();
        int row;
        for (row = rows - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
            if (board[row][column] == 0) {
            board[row][column] = currentPlayer;
            break;
            }
        }
        if (checkWin(currentPlayer)) {
            gameover = 1;
            setcolor(WHITE);
            settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
            outtextxy(180, 50, "Player ");
            setcolor(currentPlayer == 1 ? RED : YELLOW);
            outtextxy(344, 50, currentPlayer == 1 ? "RED" : "YELLOW");
            setcolor(WHITE);
            outtextxy(230, 100, " wins!");
            getch();
            cleardevice();
        } else if (row == 0) {
            draw = 1;
        }

          if (draw) {
                    // Check if all columns are full
                    int allColumnsFull = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                        if (board[0][j] == 0) {
                            allColumnsFull = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (allColumnsFull) {
                        gameover = 1;
                        setcolor(WHITE);
                        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
                        outtextxy(145, 50, "It's a draw!");
                        getch();
                        cleardevice();
                    } else {
                        draw = 0; // Reset the draw flag if there are still empty columns
                    }
                }        

        currentPlayer = 3 - currentPlayer;
        }

        } else if (menuChoice == 2) {
            drawAIMenu();
            aimenuChoice = getAIMenuChoice();

            int column;

            // Determine AI's move based on the AI menu choice
            if (aimenuChoice == 1) {
                cleardevice();
            settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
              setcolor(LIGHTGRAY);
            outtextxy(250, 215, "Loading...");
            delay(1300);
                column = easyAIMove();
            } else if (aimenuChoice == 2) {
                cleardevice();
            settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
              setcolor(LIGHTGRAY);
            outtextxy(250, 215, "Loading...");
            delay(1300);
                column = mediumAIMove();
            } else if (aimenuChoice == 3) {
                cleardevice();
            settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
              setcolor(LIGHTGRAY);
            outtextxy(250, 215, "Loading...");
            delay(1300);
                column = difficultAIMove();
            } else {
                // Handle other AI menu choices
                // ...
            }

            clearBoard();

            currentPlayer = 1;
            int gameover = 0;
            int draw = 0; // Track if the game ends in a draw
            while (!gameover) {
                cleardevice();
                drawBoard();

                if (currentPlayer == 1) {
                    int column = getPlayerMove();
                    int row;
                    for (row = rows - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
                        if (board[row][column] == 0) {
                            board[row][column] = currentPlayer;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (checkWin(currentPlayer)) {
                        gameover = 1;
                        setcolor(WHITE);
                        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
                        outtextxy(170, 50, "Player ");
                        outtextxy(344, 50, currentPlayer == 1 ? "RED" : "YELLOW");
                        outtextxy(230, 100, " wins!");
                        getch();
                        cleardevice();
                    } else if (row == 0) {
                        draw = 1; // Set the draw flag
                    }
                } else if (currentPlayer == 2) {
                    int row;
                    for (row = rows - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
                        if (board[row][column] == 0) {
                            board[row][column] = currentPlayer;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (checkWin(currentPlayer)) {
                        gameover = 1;
                        setcolor(LIGHTGREEN);
                        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
                        outtextxy(190, 55, "AI wins!");
                        getch();
                        cleardevice();
                    } else if (row == 0) {
                        draw = 1; // Set the draw flag
                    }
                }

                if (draw) {
                    // Check if all columns are full
                    int allColumnsFull = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                        if (board[0][j] == 0) {
                            allColumnsFull = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (allColumnsFull) {
                        gameover = 1;
                        setcolor(WHITE);
                        settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
                        outtextxy(145, 50, "It's a draw!");
                        getch();
                        cleardevice();
                    } else {
                        draw = 0; // Reset the draw flag if there are still empty columns
                    }
                }

                currentPlayer = 3 - currentPlayer;
            }
        }

        drawMenu();
        menuChoice = getMenuChoice();
    }

    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what seems to be the problem. Is it because the code is not updating the board properly within the getPlayerMove() fuction? Is there something wrong with the AI algorithms? Does the problem lie within the int main() body? I don't know. All I know is that I need to complete this code as soon as possible because we are going to present this to some panelists in my school.

Comment: That's a lot of code - split it up a bit so you can create some unit tests that isolate the problem, then put only the test and code under test in your question.

Comment: I agree there's too much code posted. Does the player move code work (can you place your disk where you want, and see the board update)? Maybe add some `printf`s to see what's going on. I last did Borland C++/BGI in the 1990s so I am a bit rusty on how easy it is to get the debugger to work with it.